# Arabic font ubuntu 17.10

Tags: fonts, 17.10, arabic

After upgrading to ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04, all Arabic fonts across the system look like this now.

[image]

I changed the system fonts but didn't work.

Comment: Are the default font packages for Arabic, `fonts-arabeyes` and `fonts-kacst`, installed?

Comment: does this mean that they're installed?
https://i.imgur.com/urxRzeR.png

Comment: I don't know. An easy way to find out is to open a terminal window and run the command: `sudo apt install fonts-arabeyes fonts-kacst` That will tell you if they are already installed, or install them otherwise.

Comment: I have already done that when you asked me about them...they were already installed.
what should I do next?

Comment: My belief is that with those packages present, Arabic should be rendered fine without modifications. Maybe reset to default...

Comment: did that too...still no improvement

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone else is able to help.

Comment: I believe something has changed in your browser preference if it only happens in browser. Try with a new chrome profile or a different browser.